# Core Data: NSPredicate one to many to many relations

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have a core data model like this:

[image]

But I'm having problems trying to query all the names of the songs regarles of the albums or genre.

Any of you knows how can query all the songs in core data regardless of the album or genre?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Update:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];  managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *description = [ NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Song" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Song"];
    request.entity = description;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

The results array is empty. any of you knows why or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the attempted coredata fetch request

Comment: @thelaws I have update my question with the core data fetch request

Comment: What's the code look like that is actually populating CoreData?

Comment: So what is the problem? Is `[results count] == 0` or an error?

Comment: Also, you don't need the `NSEntityDescription` if you're using `fetchRequestWithEntityName:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fetch looks fine (just skip the entity description). Step through the code and make sure:

- managed object context is not `nil`
- result of `executeFetchRequest` is not `nil` but an `NSArray`
- examine contents of the result
- if it does not contain data, log the location of your persistent store to the console (when you set up your core data stack), `cd` to the documents folder and examine the sqlite file with the `sqlite3` command line tool. Check that the records you are expecting are there.

If it works, it might be a problem with the *display* of your data rather than the retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a fetch request for that CoreData model and execute the fetch

```
NSFetchRequest *request= [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Song"];
```

Comment: I have update my post. Using fetchRequestWithEntityName the request returns empty.

Comment: Do you have items in CoreData? Has anything been saved in there? Have you setup the entire CoreData stack?

Comment: Yes I do have items in the Core Data. If I query the songs filtering by genre and album I can get the songs names